# TYPO3: Renaming of alle entities on creation of a new element

Tags: php, typo3, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I created a extsension running on TYPO3 6.2.30 that shows some products with associated materials, colors etc.

The materials, colors and products are generated by an csv import via the Backend and got persisted by the PersistenceManager.

But i have a strange behaviour if the customer wants to create a color in the Backend in the List module:

After the creation of the new Color, the name of all existing and new Colors is a (i think) randomly generated number.

**Model**:

```
class Color extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractEntity {

    /**
    * name
    *
    * @var string
    * @validate NotEmpty
    */
    protected $name = '';

    /**
     * code
     *
     * @var integer
     */
    protected $code = 0;


    /**
     * Returns the name
     *
     * @return string $name
     */
    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return void
     */
    public function setName($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the code
     *
     * @return integer $code
     */
    public function getCode() {
        return $this->code;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the code
     *
     * @param integer $code
     * @return void
     */
    public function setCode($code) {
        $this->code = $code;
    }
}
```

TCA:

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['artikel_domain_model_color'] = array(
'ctrl' => $GLOBALS['TCA']['artikel_domain_model_color']['ctrl'],
'interface' => array(
    'showRecordFieldList' => 'sys_language_uid, l10n_parent, l10n_diffsource, hidden, name, code',
),
'types' => array(
    '1' => array('showitem' => 'sys_language_uid;;;;1-1-1, l10n_parent, l10n_diffsource, hidden;;1, name, code, --div--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:tabs.access, starttime, endtime'),
),
'palettes' => array(
    '1' => array('showitem' => ''),
),
'columns' => array(
    'sys_language_uid' => array(
        'exclude' => 1,
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.language',
        'config' => array(
            'type' => 'select',
            'foreign_table' => 'sys_language',
            'foreign_table_where' => 'ORDER BY sys_language.title',
            'items' => array(
                array('LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.allLanguages', -1),
                array('LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.default_value', 0)
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'l10n_parent' => array(
        'displayCond' => 'FIELD:sys_language_uid:>:0',
        'exclude' => 1,
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.l18n_parent',
        'config' => array(
            'type' => 'select',
            'items' => array(
                array('', 0),
            ),
            'foreign_table' => 'artikel_domain_model_color',
            'foreign_table_where' => 'AND artikel_domain_model_color.pid=###CURRENT_PID### AND artikel_domain_model_color.sys_language_uid IN (-1,0)',
        ),
    ),
    'l10n_diffsource' => array(
        'config' => array(
            'type' => 'passthrough',
        ),
    ),

    't3ver_label' => array(
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.versionLabel',
        'config' => array(
            'type' => 'input',
            'size' => 30,
            'max' => 255,
        )
    ),

    'hidden' => array(
        'exclude' => 1,
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.hidden',
        'config' => array(
            'type' => 'check',
        ),
    ),
    'starttime' => array(
        'exclude' => 1,
        'l10n_mode' => 'mergeIfNotBlank',
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.starttime',
        'config' => array(
            'type' => 'input',
            'size' => 13,
            'max' => 20,
            'eval' => 'datetime',
            'checkbox' => 0,
            'default' => 0,
            'range' => array(
                'lower' => mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d'), date('Y'))
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'endtime' => array(
        'exclude' => 1,
        'l10n_mode' => 'mergeIfNotBlank',
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.endtime',
        'config' => array(
            'type' => 'input',
            'size' => 13,
            'max' => 20,
            'eval' => 'datetime',
            'checkbox' => 0,
            'default' => 0,
            'range' => array(
                'lower' => mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d'), date('Y'))
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'name' => array(
        'exclude' => 1,
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:artikel/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:artikel_domain_model_color.name',
        'config' => array(
            'type' => 'input',
            'size' => 30,
            'eval' => 'trim,required'
        ),
    ),
    'code' => array(
        'exclude' => 1,
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:artikel/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:artikel_domain_model_color.code',
        'config' => array(
            'type' => 'input',
            'size' => 4,
            'eval' => 'int,required'
        )
    )
),
);
```

ext_tables.php

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addLLrefForTCAdescr('artikel_domain_model_color', 'EXT:artikel/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_csh_artikel_domain_model_color.xlf');
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::allowTableOnStandardPages('artikel_domain_model_color');
$GLOBALS['TCA']['artikel_domain_model_color'] = array(
'ctrl' => array(
    'title' => 'LLL:EXT:artikel/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:artikel_domain_model_color',
    'label' => 'name',
    'label_alt' => 'code',
    'label_alt_force' => 1,
    'tstamp' => 'tstamp',
    'crdate' => 'crdate',
    'cruser_id' => 'cruser_id',
    'dividers2tabs' => TRUE,
    'sortby' => 'name',
    'versioningWS' => 2,
    'versioning_followPages' => TRUE,
    'languageField' => 'sys_language_uid',
    'transOrigPointerField' => 'l10n_parent',
    'transOrigDiffSourceField' => 'l10n_diffsource',
    'delete' => 'deleted',
    'enablecolumns' => array(
        'disabled' => 'hidden',
        'starttime' => 'starttime',
        'endtime' => 'endtime',
    ),
    'searchFields' => 'name,code,',
    'dynamicConfigFile' => \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::extPath($_EXTKEY) . 'Configuration/TCA/Color.php',
    'iconfile' => \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::extRelPath($_EXTKEY) . 'Resources/Public/Icons/artikel_domain_model_color.gif'
),
);
```

Any ideas why this happens or where i should start debugging?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Dimitri say, the `sortby` is the parameter for the table field which TYPO3 use to save the sorting information.

Read online
`https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/7.6/Reference/Ctrl/Index.html#sortby`

But if you want to sort the entries in backend by a custom field like name, just use the `default_sortby`.

Read online
`https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/7.6/Reference/Ctrl/Index.html#default-sortby`

With the `default_sortby` you can provide any TCA registered field in that table. If you not use the `sortby` field or don't want that backend users can sort the entries by hand, i recommend you to remove `sortby` completely from the parameters. In that case the arrows for sorting disappear too in the lists, and there can be not coming up some misunderstood why the entries in BE can be sorted with no effect in FE

Answer (score 2):

remove the `'sortby' => 'name',` from the TCA in your `ext_tables.php`. The sort field is an integer field and is automatically updated by Typo3, it is not supposed to be a textfield editable by the user

Comment: Thanks! 
But why TYPO3 is then renaming all entities? Does it initiate a new "sorting" behaviour?

Comment: Every time you create a new entry or sort a single one the whole list is being sorted so the `sortby` field gets a new value

Comment: Ok - seems legit. Is it possible to add a check at this position, if the current field is a string or int to throw an error if its set to a wrong field?

Comment: No, but if you just need it for the sorting in the backend you can use the `default_sortby` field that Manfred mentioned